# Senser based programming in Android

Tags: android, sensors

Which sensor is used to count the step of human body?
I will try to develop this type of application,  But right now I don't have any idea of this

So please help in this scenario

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#STRING_TYPE_STEP_COUNTER

Answer (score 0):

Here's one to consider:  [MMA9553L pedometer sensor](http://www.nxp.com/products/sensors/intelligent-sensors-and-sensor-hubs/intelligent-pedometer-sensor:MMA9553L)
The Linux Kernel has driver support for it already.